# How can I use css to position my form which I only have the shortcode for in wordpress please?

Tags: css

themaaximumlife.com][1](http://www.themaaximumlife.com)

I used a plugin which gives me a shortcode to create a "single-line" optin form and integrate it with my mail list service "Aweber"as you can see.

The plugin is called optin forms.

I used php to echo that shortcode in the header.php file so it's at the top as you can see. I want to reposition this form so that it is on the same plane, floating to the right of the Wolf icon and the words The Maaximum Life, not above it.

Not sure how to declare a class, div for this shortcode and use css to reposition it. Please advise

Comment: You will need to echo the shortcode right below `#site-branding`. If you are using a theme, there may be a CSS file that you can add styling to.

The shortcode generates HTML that already has a class and id that you can target. You will have to float the form right using the following CSS: `#optinforms-form1-container { float: right }`

Comment: Do you know what file #site-branding is located in(main.php, header.php)?

Comment: I can't say for sure without having more context into your project structure, but if the theme is built like most typical themes, I would assume that `#site-branding` is located in `header.php`.

Comment: Your float, css worked. See www.themaaximumlife.com

Comment: Can I not bring the form down by using y margin, x margin property in css?

Comment: @user1351880 A top margin would push the form and the rest of the content down the page. I have changed the default 10 pixels to 100 and this was the result. Are you trying to achieve something different?

Comment: The document flow would be disrupted if you were to enforce positioning on the form. The easiest solution would be to lexically (physically) change the position of the element.

Can you show me a snippet of where you echo the shortcode? What lines are above or below it?

Comment: You said this was the result?> Can I see what you see when you do that? Anyway you can share. I just basically want to bring the form below my social icons, right now it is above it.

Comment: do_action( 'decree_before_wp_head' );

 wp_head(); ?>
 
 

 <?php
echo do_shortcode('[optinform]'); 
?>
 
</head>







<body <?php body_class(); ?>> is a snippet of shortcode and shows lines above/below it in header.php

Comment: btw I'm referencing the site in desktop mode, not mobile.

Comment: I figured it out. #optinforms-form1-container 


{ float: right;
position:absolute; right:80px; top:40px;


}

Comment: it works now. see www.themaaximumlife.com The form is in alignment vertically to t with thewolf icon and my header tag line. Thanks for your help man.

Comment: You shouldn't be putting code in `<head>` (not to be confused with `<header>`) tags. That's where you put meta information.

Is all this code from one big `php` file?

Comment: No I put the css code in a custom css file via a plugin, not in the header.

Comment: I just put the echo php shortode in the header.php file. The css is in a separate file. I

Comment: If you don't mind, need your help one last time. When I view my site in desktop mode, it's perfect but in mobile or phone view the form is cut off. Do you know how I would resize it or have it change size for different screen sizes so it fits within any media device's screen?